# Android, MVP, Dagger 2 and Retrofit with multiple data sources

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp, android-mvp

I have three data sources:

- A JSON API
- Github
- An XML manifest

I'm using Retrofit, with OkHttp etc, to access all of them as such:

- JSON API is deserialised with Gson
- XML Manifest returns a string, which I will deserialise
- Github returns a string which I display

The JSON and XML will deserialise using the same Entities. As such I'd like to write my MVP code to be abstract enough that it just expects the entities.

So, I wrote an interface for this

```
public interface BaseRomRepository {
    // Addons
    Call<List<AddonEntity>> getAddons(String slug);
    Call<List<AddonEntity>> getAddons(int id);

    Call<AddonEntity> getAddon(String slug);
    Call<AddonEntity> getAddon(int id);

    // Versions
    Call<List<VersionEntity>> getVersions(String slug);
    Call<List<VersionEntity>> getVersions(int id);

    Call<VersionEntity> getVersion(String slug);
    Call<VersionEntity> getVersion(int id);
}
```

So, my Presenters and Interactors can simply call these methods and it should depend on the implementation on which Repository is actually used.

However this is where I'm stuck. I'm unsure on the best way to do this with Dagger 2. I'm sure it lends itself to this use case but I'm struggling to figure out where/how to do this.

Am I right with this? The repositories and the deserialisation comfortably live within the Model of MVP. All that should happen there and the Presenter layer can be relatively unaware of which repository is being used?

I'd show more code but it's very messy and would be hard for me to abstract into a more readable way right now.

EDIT:

Here's a Gist containing some of the implmentations I've got so far: https://gist.github.com/MatthewBooth/e3dd7a1f3a19fa0fd18e811752170be6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide different implementations of the same interface you can create a `@Module` class, and use `@Named` annotations.

In your module:

```
@Provides
@Named("xmlRepository")
BaseRomRepository provideXmlRepository() {
    return new XmlRepository();
}

@Provides
@Named("restRepository")
BaseRomRepository provideRestRepository() {
    return new RestRepository();
}

@Provides
@Named("githubRepository")
BaseRomRepository provideGithubRepository() {
    return new GithubRepository();
}
```

That way in code you can simply use:

```
@Inject
@Named("xmlRepository")
BaseDomRepository xmlRepo;
@Inject
@Named("githubRepository")
BaseDomRepository githubRepo;
@Inject
@Named("restRepository")
BaseDomRepository restRepo;
```

Or in your module

```
@Provides
@Singleton
AddonInteractor providesAddonInteractor(@Named("xmlRepository") BaseRomRepository repository) {
    return new AddonInteractorImpl<>(repository);
}
```

EDIT: I'm gonna keep what's above, cause I think it can be useful for someone else.

As we dug into it a bit further in the comment it seems OP wants a different approach.

You don't need @Named annotations. Such cases are handled using Application Variants. You create 3 app flavors: rest, xml, github. You keep all of your code in `main`. Then you put 3 implementations of, let's say `RepositoryModule`, each of which instantiates the proper version of your `BaseDomRepository`.

See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: also I recommend using the scope of singletons to avoid scoping!

Comment: It depends on the actual app and architecture and is definitely not applicable to any application. Sometimes you want to replace your data providers when: another user logs in, you select a different subscription, etc.

Scopes are a different topic.

Comment: in this case actually you want , consider returning same type during the life time of the app, how would it cope with it,

Comment: I think we lack information here to decide whether we need proper scoping or singletons are ok.

Comment: I'll add an edit with a Gist, I think scoping may be needed (you guys can tell me more I guess) but that opens another can of worms as thus far I haven't used anything other than @Singleton so I'm unfamiliar

Comment: agreed I think we do,

Comment: There's a Gist in the question now, but here it is again: https://gist.github.com/MatthewBooth/e3dd7a1f3a19fa0fd18e811752170be6

Comment: Ok, I guess you don't need scoping, using singletons for these providers should be enough. So all you need to do now, to tell Dagger to provide certain implementations of the given interface, is to use different names for your dependencies.

Comment: I've added some more code. I hope it makes it clearer now. Please let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: This is what's confusing me at the moment. Where do I do that? Would that be XmlComponent and ApiComponent?

Comment: Do you want to use all of your sources at the same time?

Comment: No, just one at a time. When the app starts, a build.prop value is read and based on the value it finds under a certain field (ro.my.manifest=http://example.com/manifest.xml or ro.my.manifest=http://example.com/manifest.json), depends on which datasource will be used.

Comment: @Kryten2k35 One more question - do you want change this field after you built the application? Or you want to build different versions of the app. The name `build.prop` suggests the second option but I need to be sure

Comment: No the build.prop value won't be changing. It'll either be set during AOSP build time or manually by a ROM developer when they package up the files into a zip ready to be flashed to a device. The app itself is an OTA providing app for custom Rom developers

Comment: Ok, I think Application Variants would be best for that - have you thought about it?

Comment: Ah, what would that be? Do you mean targetting specific devices? The support list would be huge! https://romhut.com/devices

Comment: @Kryten2k35 added some explanation to the answer

Comment: No, it means building the app 3 times, with different flavor each time. You can keep your sourcesets clean, with just one class having a different implementation for every case. See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: Ach, given that this has gone over my head so far and looking at that looks way out of my scope. I plan on publishing this to the app store and having it built via the AOSP build system, the former is probably ok for build variants but makefiles are a headache enough without adding more into the mix haha

Comment: "API interfaces cannot extend other interfaces" Well, there you go. Everything I was trying to do boiled down to that anyway :/ This may be the frustration talking, or just me being entirely wrong, but this complete hassle swapping API's into presenters defeats the whole point of dependency injection. DI implementation in Java is horrible compared to Symfony 3 using PHP 7.1 (but, alas, I'd love to have Generics in PHP!)

Answer (score 0):

consider using the named and singleton annotations In dagger2.

```
@Module
public class BasicModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("basic")
    @Singleton
    public BasicServer provideBasicServer() {
        return new BasicServer();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("basic")
    @Singleton
    public BasicServer provideBasicServer() {
        return new BasicServer();
    }
}
```

> If we need two different objects of the same return type, we can use the  @Named  qualifier annotation. You will define it both where you provide the singletons ( @Provides  annotation), and where you inject them ( @Inject  annotations):

Comment: the named annotations, @Named is used to distinguish 2 objects of the same type, therefore differentiating between name and return type

Comment: The  @Singleton  annotation is used to declare to Dagger to be only initialized only once during the entire lifecycle of the application